# Derivation of time period for physical pendula without calculus

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, rigid-body-dynamics

I need to derive the following equation, ideally without using calculus:

[image]

This website ( http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pendp.html#c1 ) has a good derivation but skips an important step at the end, when stating "This is identical in form to the equation for the simple pendulum and yields a period: EQUATION ABOVE". I was wondering if there was a way to arrive to the equation without jumping through hoops. If anyone could finish my derivation I'd be very appreciative. I got as far as this:

[image: 1697397217475.png1697397158902.png]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the same step that's missing from the [derivation of the simple pendulum period](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pend.html#c2) on the same site?

Comment: Solving a _differential_ equation without calculus?

Comment: @JEB I'm aware of one derivation of the SHM period that doesn't directly involve calculus.  It basically involves looking at uniform circular motion in Cartesian coordinates, arguing that each coordinate separately is equivalent to the SHM equation, and concluding that the solutions to the SHM equation are sines & cosines with a particular period.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The movement is not uniform circular because the acceleration changes with the angle. You have no choice other than invoking calculus to find the formula

Comment: @tac I didn't mean to imply that *this* case is uniform circular motion.  I was referring to a pedagogical technique which *uses* uniform circular motion (rather than calculus) to justify the equation for the period of a simple harmonic oscillator.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

*OP:  I'm not sure this is the sort of answer you're looking for, since I wasn't clear on which point of the given derivation you were unsure about.  Please edit your answer to clarify this point and I can edit it or delete it as appropriate.*

Suppose we have an object undergoing an equation of motion of the form
$$
a = \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = - \lambda x
$$
where $\lambda$ is some positive constant.  An equation of this form arises any time the force (torque) on an object is proportional to its linear (angular) displacement.  While the conventional way of solving this equation involves differential calculus, it is possible to use familiar equations from uniform circular motion to find what the solution to the equation is, without directly tackling the notions of differential equations.

Consider an object of mass $m$ undergoing uniform circular motion with period $T$ and radius $R$.  We know that such an object will be experiencing a force of constant magnitude $F = m R \omega^2$, where $\omega = 2 \pi / T$.  We also know that this force will be directed towards the center of the circle at all times.  Finally, assuming that the object is sitting along the $x$-axis at $t = 0$, the angle it makes with the $x$-axis as a function of time is just $\theta = \omega t$;  and so (using basic trigonometry) its coordinates as a function of time are $(x,y) = R (\cos \omega t, \sin \omega t)$.

[image]

Now let us consider this motion in Cartesian coordinates.  From Newton's Second Law, we know that
$$
m a_x = F_x \qquad \& \qquad  m a_y = F_y.
$$
But by drawing similar triangles, we can also see that at any time,
$$
\frac{F_x}{F} = - \frac{x}{R} \qquad \frac{F_y}{F} = - \frac{y}{R}.
$$
Focusing on the $x$-equation, this means that $F_x = - Fx/R = - m \omega^2$;  and so Newton's Second Law in the $x$-direction is
$$
a_x = - \omega^2 x.
$$
Similarly, $a_y = - \omega^2 y$.

In other words, Newton's Second Law for an object moving in uniform circular motion, when you look at each Cartesian direction separately, is of the form $a = - \lambda x$, with $\lambda = \omega^2$.  But we know that for an object in circular motion, we have periodic motion with period $T = 2 \pi/\omega = 2 \pi /\sqrt{\lambda}$.  This implies that for *any* object moving under the influence of an equation of the form $a = - \lambda x$, the resulting motion will be periodic with period $T = 2 \pi/\sqrt{\lambda}$.

In the case you're concerned about from HyperPhysics, you have $\lambda = m g L_{cm} / I$, and so
$$
T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{m g L_{cm}}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you (at least) can write down the 2nd Newton law for harmonic oscillator: mass $m$ with spring of stiffness $k$,
$$F_x=-kx$$
For simple harmonic oscillator it is given by
$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}.$$
One more time: for mathematical pendulum you can write down the 2nd Newton law in form
$$F_x=-\frac{mgx}{L},$$
where we have assumed that the angle is small and $\sin(x/L)\approx x/L$. The period is
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}.$$
These two answers are similar to each other. It happens because the equation of motion in both systems is the same.  If you avoid differential equations and you are not a student of high-school, you can think about this coincidence in terms of energy conservation. For harmonic oscillator, we have
$$E=\frac{mv^2}{2}+\frac{kx^2}{2}=\text{const}.$$
For mathematical pendulum, we have
$$E=\frac{mv^2}{2}+\frac{mg}{L}\frac{x^2}{2}=\text{const}.$$
Comparing these two equations and keeping in mind the answers for periods, we can propose the following. Equation of motion for (conservative & small) oscillations in the most general form looks as
$$F_{x}=-k_{\text{eff}}x,$$
where $k_{\text{eff}}$ is so-called effective stiffness and $x$ is the generalized coordinate. The total energy of this system can be represented as
$$E=\frac{k_{\text{eff}}x^2}{2}+\frac{m_{\text{eff}}v^2}{2},$$
where $m_{\text{eff}}$ is the effective mass. Here we measure the potential energy from equilibrium position, i.e  potential energy is zero at equilibrium. Technically, you have to:

1. Write the expression for total energy
2. Extract coefficients at squared displacement $x$ ($k_{\text{eff}}$) and squared velocity $v$ ($m_{\text{eff}}$)
3. Find $\omega=\sqrt{k_{\text{eff}}/m_{\text{eff}}}$
4. Compute $T=2\pi/\omega$.

Now, for your system. We write the energy conservation law:
$$E=\frac{I_{\text{support}}\omega^2}{2}+mgL_{\text{CM}}(1-\cos\theta).$$
For small angle $\theta$, we can assume that $1-\cos\theta \approx\theta^2/2$. The energy becomes
$$E=\frac{I_{\text{support}}\omega^2}{2}+\frac{mgL_{\text{CM}}\theta^2}{2}.$$
The angular frequency plays role of "velocity", so $I_{\text{support}}$ corresponds to $m_{\text{eff}}$. The angle $\theta$ plays role of displacement, so $mgL_{\text{CM}}$ corresponds to $k_{\text{eff}}$. Finally,
$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{mgL_{\text{CM}}}{I_{\text{support}}}}\rightarrow \boxed{T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{I_{\text{support}}}{mgL_{\text{CM}}}}}.$$

We "avoid" calculus, but we assume that expression for periods of mathematical pendulum & harmonic pendulum is known. Also, we assume that we know how to write 2nd Newton law for this systems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it means to get that result ''without using calculus''. A possible approach could be to get the equation of motion for your system and compare it to the one for the pendulum. This idea can be developed in multiple frameworks, but I will give you an example using the lagrangian formalism.

The kinetic energy of your system is purely rotational and it is $T = I_\text{support} \dot{\theta}^2 / 2$. On the other hand, the potential energy $U$ (taking as reference for $U = 0$ the vertical coordinate of the attachment point) is $U = -mgL_\text{cm}\cos\theta$. Therefore, the lagrangian for your system is
$$
L = \dfrac{1}{2} I_\text{support} \dot{\theta}^2 + mgL_\text{cm}\cos\theta\ .
$$

We can use the Euler-Lagrange equations to get the equation of movement:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} \right) - \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \ddot{\theta} + \dfrac{mgL_\text{cm}}{I_\text{support}} \sin\theta = 0\ .
$$

Now, the equation of motion for a pendulum is
$$
\ddot{\theta} + \omega^2 \sin\theta = 0\ ,
$$
where $\omega = 2\pi / T$. Therefore, comparing both equations, your system behaves as a pendulum with period
$$
T = 2\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{I_\text{support}}{mgL_\text{cm}}}\ .
$$

This is a way of solving your problem, but again, I don't know what it means to not use calculus... I had to compute a pair of derivatives of the lagrangian.

Comment: Yes, you can't avoid using calculus because the acceleration is not constant

Answer (score 0):

Once saw a non-rigorous derivation using unit analysis that might serve as a useful mnemonic.

Period has units of time. A pendulum has length, a mass, and is moving in a gravityfield.

$s = (kg)^am^b(m/s^2)^c$

$s$ is seconds, $kg$ is mass, $m/s^2$ are units of $g$.

Since particles move the same in a gravitational field regardless of their mass, we expect $a=0$.

Then we have:

$b+c=0$

$-2c=1$

$\implies c=(-1/2), b=(1/2)$

$T=C\sqrt{L/g}$  where $C$ is a multiplicative constant.

Period actually does depend on initial angular displacement of the pendulum. That displacement is unitless, so unit analysis won't be very useful when accounting for it. Further, the standard formula for the period only really works for small angular displacements $< 10^\circ$.